# Two definitions of coherent sheaf

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

There are at least two ways to define a (quasi)coherent sheaf on the scheme $(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$, namely the one given in Hartshorne's "Algebraic geometry" (I guess you know it: it is given in terms of "abstract" modules) and the second close to Wikipedia's one: $\mathcal{O}_X$-module $\mathcal{F}$ is quasicoherent if and only if each point has a neighbourhood $U$ such that the sequence 
$$\bigoplus_{i\in I} \mathcal{O}_U\to \bigoplus_{j\in J} \mathcal{O}_U\to \mathcal{F}|_{U}\to 0$$
is exact.
Moreover, $\mathcal{F}$ is coherent on noetherian $X$ if $J$ can be chosen finite.

How can I prove these definitions are equivalent? I'm sorry if the question is childish: I am a beginner in schemes and such kind of geometry.

Comment: I guess one thing to say to the beginner is these technical questions are things you can spend more or less forever chasing and at the end of the journey you won't be any closer to understanding "geometry". That said, it's a fine question!

Comment: One direction, by the way, is easy. From Hartshorne's definition: on $U = \operatorname{Spec} A$ you have $\mathcal{F}|_U = \widetilde{M}$. Present $M$ as $A^R \to A^G \to M \to 0$ and apply the exact functor $\widetilde{\phantom{M}}$. For the other direction you need to know some facts about the category of quasicoherent (in Hartshorne's sense) modules.

Comment: @Hoot's first comment is spot on. The best way to test your understanding is to find a non quasi-coherent sheaf (using whichever definition you want).

Comment: In order to prove the direction not covered by Hoot's above comment, it might be convenient to prove the following as an intermediary step: If the $\mathcal{O}_X$-module $\mathcal{F}$ is quasi-coherent (exact sequence definition), then for any open affine $U = \operatorname{Spec} A \subset X$ and any $f \in A$ the natural homomorphism $\Gamma(U,\mathcal{F})_f \to \Gamma(D(f),\mathcal{F})$ is an isomorphism. Here, $D(f)$ denotes the principal open subset $\lbrace \mathfrak{p} \in \operatorname{Spec} A \mid f \notin \mathfrak{p} \rbrace$.

Answer (score 1):

The other definition is that there's an affine cover on each set $U=\text{Spec } A$ of which $\mathcal F$ is the cokernel of a map of sheaves of the form $\widetilde{\mathcal M}\to \widetilde{\mathcal N}$. The cokernel of a sheaf map is not generally a sheaf, but $\widetilde{\bullet}$ is an equivalence of categories from $A$-modules to quasicoherent $\mathcal{O}_A$-modules, so the cokernel must be $\widetilde{M/N}$. But we can write $M/N$ as the cokernel of a map of free $A$-modules (that's what a presentation is,) so we can $\widetilde{M/N}$ as the cokernel of a map of free $\mathcal{O}_A$-modules.